# Mirth Connect Solution.For multiple user Access info with what they Done with there name and date

Tags: mirth

my mirth connect uses 10 people simultaneously
EX . one reprocoss hl7 message and another user Remove  Message.

So i want to which user will which process with time and date and ip address

plz suggestion it important

Answer (score 0):

The commercial version of Mirth Connect supports advanced user management and advanced alerting, which sounds like what you need.

From the [Mirth Site](https://www.nextgen.com/Interoperability/Mirth-Solutions/Connect-Extensions?tab=true):

**Advanced Alerting**
Advanced Alerting provides metric, exception, and state-based monitoring of channels and connectors. Additional features include automatic escalation and de-escalation, scheduling, and notification throttling. Using advanced alerts, dynamically send different alert messages to different user groups based on the current escalation level, time, and day. The new alert dashboard provides a view of all alert statistics and logs.

**User Authorization**
User Authorization provides role-based access control to all aspects of the Mirth Connect Administrator. Create new roles with specific permissions to areas such as channel management or message browsing. Assign any number of roles to users. Use this to manage access to sensitive channel and messaging data across your enterprise.

Comment: From the [Mirth site](https://www.nextgen.com/Interoperability/Mirth-Solutions/Connect-Extensions?tab=true)